# setTimeout() - anonymous function syntax fires twice on page load

Tags: javascript, settimeout, onload

Following are the samples of my index.html file and the script.js file it includes:

```js
main();

function main() {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    console.log('test');
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      main();
    }, 1000);
    //setTimeout('main', 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript: main();">
</body>

</html>
```

For some reason, `setTimeout(function() { main(); }, 1000);` calls `main()` twice, whereas `setTimeout('main', 1000);` calls it once. Shouldn't the two produce the same result? What am I missing?

Comment: `setTimeout('main', 1000);` doesn’t do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is running `main()` twice. Once on the first line of your js file, and again in the `onload` attribute of the `body` tag.

I recommend you remove the `onload` handler from the `body` tag.

Comment: Damn it, this is an extremely stupid oversight on my part. Not only have I incorrectly applied the second version of the syntax, I have also completely forgotten about the `onload` attribute. Thank you. That's why sleeping is important, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually doing what you think. `setTimeout('main', 1000)` is doing nothing, because it's invalid code. It should be `setTimeout(main, 1000)`.

The reason it looks like it's running twice is because you have `onload="javascript: main();"` in your `body` tag, and also call `main();` at the top of your JavaScript.

Comment: `setTimeout('main', 1000)` is totally valid! When given a string, setTimeout will `eval` it. `"main"` won't actually execute the function... but the code is syntactically good.

Comment: @JoeFrambach You're right, I was thinking it wasn't valid as far as making `main()` execute.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<body onload="javascript: main();">` called function once and your also called main function at the beginning of your JavaScript code.